# Full setup of Transform Feedback(openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, feedback

GLSL 1.50, openGL 3.3.

I've been lately trying to get my tranform feedback working but without success. I still receive error after glBeginTranformFeedback() and as I haven't found any full working code I have stacked up my knowledge with some code that I found and documentation, it should be working well by now but I am missing something. So if anybody got full code (initializing of buffers, setting up, updating, rendering, reading back) it would definitelly help and if you don't but know what's going on you could take look at my code. I excluded some benchmarking, handling of windows and it's creation:

```
int main()
{
    bool fullsize = false, paused = false; 
    std::string caption = "Tester";

    GLuint dataVAO,speedUpdateVBO,dataVBO;
    std::vector<vector3f> dataW;

    // Create the main rendering window

    init(); //just some camera commands

    UniShader shader; //my shader class keeps everything together
    shader.init();
    shader.addShader("test.vert");
    shader.addShader("test.frag");
    shader.newAttributeVariable("speed");
    shader.newFeedbackVarying("sp");
    shader.linkShader();
    shader.use();

    //init some data
    dataW.push_back(vector3f(0,1,0));

    //creating VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&dataVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(dataVAO);
    //creating VBO
    glGenBuffers(1,&dataVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,dataVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vector3f), 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader.getAttributeIndex("speed"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &speedUpdateVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, speedUpdateVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, sizeof(vector3f), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, speedUpdateVBO); 
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    while (App.IsOpened())
    {
            App.SetActive();
        benchP = Clock.GetElapsedTime();

        //update calls
        if(!paused)
            //update
        benchU = Clock.GetElapsedTime();

        //render calls
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glColor3f(0.6f,0.7f,0.7f);

    GLuint query;
    GLuint count = 0;

    glGenQueries(1, &query);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.getAttributeIndex("speed"));

    glBindVertexArray(dataVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,dataVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vector3f)*dataW.size(), &dataW[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, speedUpdateVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, sizeof(vector3f)*dataW.size(), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, speedUpdateVBO); 
    glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
    glBeginQuery(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN, query);
    printOglError(); //Until this everything OK, I think
    glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS); 
    printOglError(); //This one prints out Invalid Value

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,dataW.size());

    glEndTransformFeedback();
    glEndQuery(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN); 
    glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

    //retrieve updated data
    glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &count); //count is 0 -> nothing happend

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.getAttributeIndex("speed"));

    glDeleteQueries(1, &query);

    App.Display();
    //some other benchmark stuff
}
```

shaders:
vert

```
#version 150 core
in vec3 speed;

varying vec3 sp;

const float gravity_constant = 9.81f;

void main(){
    sp = speed;
    sp += vec3(0,-gravity_constant,0);
}
```

frag

```
#version 150 core
varying vec3 sp;

void main (void)
{
    vec3 c = sp;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(c,1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader is there just for GLSL optimalization. If sp wouldn't be used GLSL would clear it up.
There may be some minor bugs as I extracted this from much larger code with multiple varyings that fails aswell.

Comment: Can you post shader class implementation? Also, tell us what platform are you running on and what is the driver version.

Comment: May I ask you to repeat the experiment, but with no fragment shader attached to the program (only the vertex one)? Don't worry about `sp` value being optimized out by GLSL compiler - it won't be (I have tons of TF shaders without any FP components attached).

Comment: Well I think I can really take it from that point as that sample pack got it everything simple and easy. But I can't ask for more than someone's helping me so, shader class will be in edit, I'm running on windows 7, ATI radeon 3870HD. Catalyst Control Centre 10.6 with openGL version 6.14.10.9901 (something arround 3.3). Clearing fragment shader to "void main(){}" gives same error. Excluding shader from loading gives same error..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenGL Samples Pack](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/OGLSamples/). You might be interested in ogl-330-transform-feedback.cpp and ogl-400-transform-feedback-object.cpp. You might even check [January 2011 OpenGL drivers status](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0373.html) whether latest drivers have any issues with the provided examples.

Good luck.

Comment: Seems like these samples could finally guide me from darkness :D Yes they're perfect just what I need. Will need to rebuild my app a bit though so I hope it'll finally work. I noticed that they're binding same buffer object as vertexArray and feedbackBuffer.. and from that point they must specify pointers.. that's should be it

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Rakos has a demo with source code, implementing instance culling using transform feedback on OpenGL. It might help to look at it :

http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/02/instance-culling-using-geometry-shaders/

Comment: 1. nice program, now I know that my problem isn't driver/card related and there's a source code also.. mhmm tasty.. 2. (just for info) he was running at 6-7 frames, me at 70-210.. lol and it's just one series difference :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Ogre 3D:
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=299736

They seem to have a working implementation of transform feedback.

Comment: uhm it will be like searching needle in the pile but until someone posts something better I'll try to run through it. I think I know where to start, but ogre is big engine and there could be some initializations hidden in other code. Thanks for fast answer though! :)

Comment: Ok dug in it and found something. I swapped the order of calls but it still gives error on glBeginTranformFeedback aswell as on glEndTransformFeedback. First difference other than that they're using their large interface is that they're still using NV extension, but I'm running on ATI and they're using interleaved arrays but I need separate. It shouldn't write those error anyway so something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced a similar problem that `glBeginTransformFeedback` generated "invalid operation". After I read the source code in file "gl-440-transform-feedback.cpp" from the package provided by Orhun, I found that adding

```
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
```

before `glBeginTransformFeedback()` call just solves the problem.

Hope this can help.

Comment: I didn't have to use that in my solution but I'm glad it helped. In case you would like to see, it is part of my shaders library: https://github.com/BetaRavener/UniShader/blob/master/src/UniShader/ShaderOutput.cpp . Note that this was developed against OpenGL 3.3